# Finding occurrence of specific event in a day in R

Tags: r, events, find-occurrences

I have two question

First, I want to find the number of occurrences/repetitions of a specific event after a gap in a given day using R. Below is my sample data,

| Date | Hour | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21-08-2019 | 00 | No_Event |
| 21-08-2019 | 01 | No_Event |
| 21-08-2019 | 02 | No_Event |
| 21-08-2019 | 03 | No_Event |
| 21-08-2019 | 04 | Hold |
| 21-08-2019 | 05 | Hold |
| 21-08-2019 | 06 | No_Event |
| 21-08-2019 | 07 | No_Event |
| 21-08-2019 | 08 | Hold |
| 21-08-2019 | 09 | Hold |
| 21-08-2019 | 09 | Event |

The desired output would be,

| Date | Event | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21-08-2019 | No_Event | 2 |
| 21-08-2019 | Hold | 2 |
| 21-08-2019 | Event | 1 |

Second Question,

How do I repeat this in a list that contains approximately 100 data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `Date` and `Event` you can count number of times the difference between hours is more than 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date), 
         Hour = as.numeric(Hour)) %>%
  arrange(Date, Hour) %>%
  group_by(Date, Event) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(diff(Hour) > 1) + 1, .groups = 'drop')

#  Date       Event    Count
#  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
#1 2019-08-21 Event        1
#2 2019-08-21 Hold         2
#3 2019-08-21 No_Event     2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a run-length-id sequence column on 'Event' column, do a grouping by 'Date', 'Event', get the number of distinct 'grp' created (`n_distinct`) in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(grp = rleid(Event)) %>%
     group_by(Date, Event) %>% 
     summarise(Count = n_distinct(grp), .groups = 'drop')
```

-outut

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Date       Event    Count
  <chr>      <chr>    <int>
1 21-08-2019 Event        1
2 21-08-2019 Hold         2
3 21-08-2019 No_Event     2
```

---

Or in `base R` with `rle`, create the sequence by 'Event', get the `unique` rows of selected columns, and `aggregate` to return the `length` of 'grp' grouped by Date, Event

```
aggregate(cbind(Count = grp) ~ ., unique(transform(df1,
   grp = with(rle(Event), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))[-2]), FUN = length)
        Date    Event Count
1 21-08-2019    Event     1
2 21-08-2019     Hold     2
3 21-08-2019 No_Event     2
```

---

To repeat in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
lst2 <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
       %>% 
     mutate(grp = rleid(Event)) %>%
     group_by(Date, Event) %>% 
     summarise(Count = n_distinct(grp), .groups = 'drop'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", 
"21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", 
"21-08-2019", "21-08-2019", "21-08-2019"), Hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L), Event = c("No_Event", "No_Event", 
"No_Event", "No_Event", "Hold", "Hold", "No_Event", "No_Event", 
"Hold", "Hold", "Event")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. The code works. But it returns only a single observation called 'Count"

Comment: @Karthik i showed a dreproducible example and work for both

Comment: Oops. I will check it again. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Karthik i updated the post for the list caes

Comment: @Karthik try with `dplyr::summarise(..` may be you had `plyr::summarise` masking the function